# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object but value is not null

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have a trigger that is creating a set of ID's for a custom object, Base Elements. I'm getting the System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object on the line, bepc.add(b.BMCServiceDesk__PrimaryClient__c); But I am debugging it the line before so I know that it's not null. Any idea what is going on?

This is not a test class in case anyone was wondering.

```
Set<ID> bepc; 
FOR (BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c b : [SELECT BMCServiceDesk__PrimaryClient__c FROM BMCServiceDesk__BMC_BaseElement__c WHERE BMCServiceDesk__PrimaryClient__c!=null ]) {
    system.debug('pc: '+b.BMCServiceDesk__PrimaryClient__c);
    bepc.add(b.BMCServiceDesk__PrimaryClient__c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't declaring the set of ID's correctly. I had

```
Set<ID> bepc;
```

instead of

```
Set<ID> bepc = new set<ID>();
```